# How many processes created

Tags: c, unix, fork

Hi I have a question about fork function, and how it works. I have this line:

```
fork() || fork() && fork()
```

I want to know how many processes created, and the tree of parent and child process. I've tried the code below, it returns 4 different process, is it correct?

This is what I've tried:

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    fork() || fork() && fork();
    printf("%d\n", getpid());

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try drawing the tree yourself, and you'll see.

Comment: Is it homework task? What have you tried so far? I'll give you two hints. **1**: As you can see from [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence), `&&` operation will be executed first, and `||` operation will be executed last. **2**. As you can see from [man 2 fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork): `On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent, and 0 is returned in the child`. Now you should be able to answer your question just using logic.

Comment: To be more precise, knowing how `||` and `&&` operations work, you can replace this line: `fork() || fork() && fork();` with this line: `if (fork() == 0) if (fork() != 0) fork();`

Comment: @Sam, I don't think you're correct on the order of evaluation, the standard states the `||` evaluates strictly left to right (C99/C11 6.5.14). The leftmost fork will be done first, then the result of that `||`-ed with `(fork && fork`). The precedence controls how the results are _combined_ in this case, not the order of execution. In other words, it's `fork1 || (fork2 && fork3)` rather than `(fork1 || fork2) && fork3` but `fork1` always evaluates first. If `&&` were executed first, the root process would create two children. As per my answer, it actually only creates one.

Comment: Which is kind of funny because the way it _actually_ works is the way you have it in your `if` variant, despite the fact that it's at odds with your earlier textual description. Of course, I could be misunderstanding your textual description, English is a much messier language than C :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, I had mistaken in my first comment, so I decided to fix it with my second  comment (which I actually tested). IMO, the best way to understand what is happening there, is to use explicit conditional form (using `if` operator). Anyway, AFAIU it was just homework task, so I didn't pay too much attention to this question. But now I can provide my observations (as an answer) I did back there, and you will see that I realized my mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is modify your code as follows and you'll see what processes create other processes:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int rootpid = getpid();
    printf("root: %d\n", rootpid);

    fork() || fork() && fork();
    if (rootpid == getpid())
        sleep (10);
    else
        printf("%d started by %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    return 0;
}
```

The `sleep (10)` is just to (hopefully) ensure the children finish first so the output isn't mixed up with the shell prompt.

Running that code gives you, assuming all the `fork` calls are successful<sup>1</sup>:

```
root: 8016
8892 started by 7884
7884 started by 8016
1192 started by 7884
```

so the tree would be:

```
8016 -+
      |
      +- 7884 -+
               |
               +- 8892
               |
               +- 1192
```

If you examine the code, you'll see why:

```
fork() || fork() && fork();
```

The first `fork` only happens in the root process `8016`. It returns non-zero (true) to that process so it does no further evaluation of the expression since `||` is a short-circuiting operation (`true || something` doesn't even *look* at `something`).

However, the *child* `7884` of that process gets zero (false) as the return code so carries on evaluating. It will therefore `fork` the `8892` child (with the middle `fork`) and receive non-zero from that. In this case, the `&&` causes it to go to the third `fork` and create `1192`. At that stage, it's finished evaluating the full expression and it carries on with the rest of the code.

The two children created by `7884` both receive zero (false) from the second `fork` so give up on the full expression (again, short-circuiting means that `false && something` does not evaluate `something`).

Hence they do not create any children with their third `fork`.

---

<sup>1</sup> If any of them are not, you may end up with very different results.

Answer (score 0):

### Experimental solution

Although this issue can be solved mentally, you can find yourself in situations when you are not sure if you are correct. For such cases the best thing to investigate problem is to **run an experiment**.

In this case you are not sure how your `fork() || fork() && fork()` line will be executed (neither the order of `||`/`&&` operators, nor the return code of `fork()` in each case). So you can just **wrap** the `fork()` call in your own function and see when it's being called. Check out the code below.

```c
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static pid_t my_fork(int n)
{
    pid_t res;

    printf("--- %d started ---\n", n);
    res = fork();
    if (res) {
        printf("--- %d succeed ---\n", n);
        printf("fork:  pid = %d, ppid = %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        printf("res = %d\n", res);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return res;
}

int main(void)
{
    my_fork(1) || my_fork(2) && my_fork(3);

    printf("Hello: pid = %d, ppid = %d\n\n", getpid(), getppid());

    for (;;)
        ;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Program output:

```
--- 1 started ---
--- 1 succeed ---
fork:  pid = 4770, ppid = 4697
--- 2 started ---
res = 4771

Hello: pid = 4770, ppid = 4697

--- 2 succeed ---
fork:  pid = 4771, ppid = 4770
res = 4772

--- 3 started -----------
Hello: pid = 4772, ppid = 4771

--- 3 succeed ---
fork:  pid = 4771, ppid = 4770
res = 4773

Hello: pid = 4771, ppid = 4770

Hello: pid = 4773, ppid = 4771
```

So the process tree is:

```
 4770-+
 |    |
 |    4771-+-------+
 |    |    |       |
 |    |    4772    4773
 |    |    |       |
 |    |    |       |

\________  _________/
         \/
   printf("Hello");
```

Now the program is spinning in the infinite loop (`for (;;)`), and you can stop the execution of program (`Ctrl+Z`) to confirm the actual process tree using `ps` tool:

```
$ ps auxf
```

Output:

```
PID      COMMAND

4697     \_ -bash
4770         \_ ./a.out
4771             \_ ./a.out
4772                 \_ ./a.out
4773                 \_ ./a.out
```

To close the program, run `fg` command and press `Ctrl+C`.

### Logical solution

To figure out this problem logically, you can use next facts.

#### Precedence and order of execution

The [precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) shows that `&&` operator has bigger priority.
So the original code:

```c
fork() || fork() && fork();
```

can be replaced with:

```c
fork() || (fork() && fork());
```

From [C99 6.5.14](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.14.html) we know that:

> the `||` operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation

So fork sequence can be further replaced with:

```c
if (fork() == 0)
    if (fork() != 0)
        fork();
```

#### `fork()` return value

From "man 2 fork":

> On success, the PID of the child process is returned in the parent,
>   and 0 is returned in the child

So at this point we can draw process tree, using conditional code above and knowledge about `fork()` mechanics:

```
root-----+
|        |
|     (fork1)
|        |
|        child1---+---------+
|        |        |         |
|        |     (fork2)   (fork3)
|        |        |         |
|        |        child2    child3
|        |        |         |
|        |        |         |
```